# How technical should my oral PhD defense be?

Tags: phd, united-states, physics, defense, electrical-engineering

I thought this would make a good question, and will ask my advisor shortly.

In the fields of **optical sciences, electrical engineering, or applied physics at an RU/VH institution in the United States,** how technical should the oral PhD defense be?

My last conference talk did not get any questions (on the same topics in my dissertation), so I believe that my presentations may be overly technical.

For some context : This work, some recent work by my former labmate, and recent work in this same niche by my advisor have been heavy on the mathematical/theory side, and none of us have received many questions at recent conferences.

Comment: What country?  This varies significantly from nation to nation.

Comment: The only people who can answer this dquestion are the members of your defense committee, Ask them.

Comment: I would go for a combination, just as the most successful children's movies do -- so that everyone who attended leaves feeling they got something out of it.  However, I would aim for one-third or one-fourth for the proportion of material aimed at the common denominator.  Your defense is quite different from a conference talk.  In your defense, your original research must take center stage, and if that is very mathematical, then you get to be very mathematical in your defense.  If there's one place you shouldn't have to water things down, it's in your defense.

Answer (score 6):

You need to find out what the standard is in *your* department, since it varies. You can:

- ask your advisor
- attend other defense presentations in your department
- ask students in your department who have successfully defended

Comment: Better yet: do all three.

Comment: For the second and third points, I have, and the standard varies greatly. When my advisor wakes up I'll ask him (he is in another time zone at the moment).